# Properly scale map for multiple screen sizes on python's folium

Tags: python, folium

I'm publishing a map [here](https://elcook.eu.pythonanywhere.com/), that captures the mouse click position and sends it to an API where it is used to plot a meteogram (only works for Longitudes between 60W and 80 E, feel free to use it if you find it useful).

I've published it on pythonanywhere and it runs with flask as an app. The map and buttons are created using the folium library.

Everything works fine except on mobile screen where I can't find a way to properly scale the map and its elements (+ and - zoom buttons for example) when viewing on portrait mode. It works fine on landscape, but I would like it to be better on portrait mode also.

My code below

```
import folium,branca
from flask import Flask
from folium.plugins import LocateControl

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["Debug"] = True
@app.route('/')

def index():
    start_coords = (38, -8)
    fig=branca.element.Figure(height="100%",width="100%")

    m=folium.Map(location=start_coords, zoom_start=4,max_bounds=True)

    e=folium.LatLngPopup()
    m.add_child(e)

    LocateControl(strings={'drawMarker':'false'}).add_to(m)

    fig.add_child(m)

    return m._repr_html_()
```

I've tried to add the following line after creating the map object:

```
m.get_root().header.add_child(folium.Element('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,'
'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />'))
```

like in the example [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/842). But I don't see anything happening.

I'm not sure if its because folium creates everything inside an iframe, or I'm just simply not adding the right code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!